# positioning an anchor link in the middle of a box with set dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have created a circle that should have the link Read more positioned dead center using the layout I have created here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/pAGYc/14/ can anyone advise on how this positioning can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line-height equivalent to the circle radius to the .more paragraph class as shown in:

[line-height](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocorreia/pAGYc/17/)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it, if you know the text isn't going to wrap (such as if you know the text is always going to be "Read More" or something of similar length). You can set display to inline-block (inline-block allows you to use attributes for inline elements and block elements in your CSS) on your `a` and set the line-height.

[Here's a fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/ybc54/5/)